# Bootstrap-multiselect onChange event doesnt fire on select all or deselect all

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

When I select Select All - the change event should automatically get called, But its not working.When I select one by one, change event worked but not worked for select all.

Answer (score 2):

try it dear

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            includeSelectAllDivider: true,
            maxHeight: 400,
            onSelectAll: function () {
                console.log("select-all-nonreq");
            },
            onDeselectAll: function () {
                console.log("deselect-all-nonreq");
            }
        });
```